# Liked time of request.user is not showing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I just started learning Django. I am building a simple Blog App and I am trying to `get the user liked time of post of request.user`.

I made a `Post` model and a `Like` model. And when user like show the like time of user.

But it is not showing the liked time.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')

class Likepost(models.Model):
    by_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_of = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_liked = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def blog_post_detail(request, post_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    accessLikes = obj.likepost_set.all()

    for All in accessLikes:
        if request.user == All.by_user
            All.request.user.date_liked

    context = {'obj':obj}
    return render(request, 'blog_post_detail.html', context}
```

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to access `liked time of request.user`

It is keep showing :-

> Likepost' object has no attribute 'request'

I will really appreciate your help. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the `Likepost` object of a user by filtering the queryset, and try to retrieve the corresponding like:

```
def blog_post_detail(request, post_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    likepost = obj.likepost_set.filter(by_user=request.user).first()

    context = {'obj':obj, 'likepost': likepost}
    return render(request, 'blog_post_detail.html', context}
```

Next you can render this in the template with:

```
{% if likepost %}
    Liked by you at {{ likepost.date_liked }}
{% endif %}
```

Normally one can prevent multiple `Likepost`s for the same object and the same user with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint):

```
class Likepost(models.Model):
    by_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_of = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_liked = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['by_user', 'post_of'],
                name='like_once_per_post'
            )
        ]
```

If you plan to store both like and unlike events, you get the most recent `Like`model with:

```
def blog_post_detail(request, post_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    likepost = obj.likepost_set.filter(by_user=request.user).order_by('-date_liked').first()
    # …
```

Comment: Thank you very Much, It worked. Can i use `.first()` always ? I mean *In liking post  it (The Like) will always be first, will it* ?

Comment: @Onsem: normally you add a constrait that the same object can not be liked multiple times. That can be done with a [**`UniqueConstraint(fields=['by_user', 'post_of'], name='some_name')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint). In that case, `.first()` will fetch the one, and then only one `Likepost` object for that user and that product.

Comment: I will implement `edit` (I mean unlike) in future, Still can i make this with `UniqueConstrint` ? So when user dislike then like will be remove and he/she ca again like it .

Comment: @Onsem: if you remove the `Likepost` in case of unliking, yes.

Comment: I will create another model for Dislike, So should i still use `Unique Constraint` ?

Comment: @Onsem: it that case no, you can fetch the most recent `Likepost` with a `.order_by('-date_liked')` clause.

Comment: Now i understand by your great explanation. Thanks again, It was really helpful.